# Asp.Net MVC 4 routing and link generation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, parameters, include, routes

In ASP.NET MVC 4 I wonder about the behavior, how links are generated for me.

Imagine a simple controller with 3 actions, each taking an integer parameter "requestId", for example:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int requestId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult About(int requestId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact(int requestId)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and this registered route (before the default route):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Testroute",
    url: "home/{action}/{requestId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

I call my index-view using `http://localhost:123/home/index/8`

On this view, I render links for the other two actions:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText1", "About")
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText2", "Contact")
```

Now I expect MVC to render this links including the current route-value for "requestId", like this:

```
http://localhost:123/home/about/8
http://localhost:123/home/contact/8
```

But i get these links (without the paramter):

```
http://localhost:123/home/about
http://localhost:123/home/contact
```

...but not for the index-action if i would specify one:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText3", "Index")
```

What I want to avoid is to explicitly specify the parameters in this manner:

```
@Html.ActionLink("LinkText1", "Contact", new { requestId = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["requestId"] })
```

When I move the requestId parameter before the action paramter it works like I expect it, but I don't want to move it:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Testroute",
    url: "home/{requestId}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Can someone explain me this behavior? How can I get this to work without specifying the parameter explicitly?

Comment: I have the same question. :\

Answer (score 0):

InController:
      Replace the int to nullable int

For Routing:
set requestId as optional in routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Testroute",
    url: "home/{action}/{requestId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" ,requestId=RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the behavior is still the same when I call http://localhost:123/home/index/8. I except to have the request parameter "8" included in all of the links.